# what is alternate to first() to import whole string in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

What is alternate method to first() to check whole string?
suppose my csv have string "nike hello" then its only checking "nike" first element but i want to check whole string "nike hello".

```
$brand = Brand::query()->where('slug',$brandName)->first();
if($brand){
   return $brand->id;
}
```

Comment: where will check whole string .check once db has exact value.

Comment: "before importing to db. i first checking string exist in db or not?" - @JohnLobo

Comment: Can you please explain what you trying to achive? I didn't actually get what do you want to do

Comment: Right now you are checking if $brand->slug is exactly $brandName

Comment: AidOnline01  - i want to check weather full name exist or not if yes then i assigning id to brand and if not then creating new brand and assigning id to it.  im checking it because i dont want to import same brand again and again

Comment: yes 'slug' is in db column where name imported

Comment: i want alteration to first() to check full string not just first text.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `first()` does. `Brand::query()->where('slug',$brandName)` returns a collection, `first()` will return the first object in that collection

Comment: catcon - yes i want to return whole object in collection by replacing first() like "nike hello" not just "nike"

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly but you can replace `->first()` by `->get()` to get the whole collection.

Comment: $brand = Brand::query()->where('slug',$brandName)->get($brandName);
        if($brand){
            return $brand->id;
        }else{
            $newBrand = [
                'name'=>$brandName,
                'is_active'=>"1",
                'meta'=>[
                    'meta_title'=>null,
                    'meta_description'=>null,
                ]
            ];
            $brand = Brand::create($newBrand);
            return $brand->id;
        }
    }

Comment: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance when i use ->get()  -@catcon

Comment: `get()` doesn't need a parameter - are you sure, you're using it right?

Comment: no i just change first() to get() - @shaedrich

Comment: im trying since 9 days but didnt get any solution... if anyone can have... share with full solution